# Does adding a csv file to a wordpress plugin introduce security risks to the site?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-security-policy

I am currently working on an implementation reading data from a csv file from within a WordPress plugin. It was suggested the file be added within the plugin in an assets directory. I have concerns in doing this. In particular, I'm worried about security and whether this makes the site vulnerable to attacks.

That being said, I looked at the assets folder in the frontend on my local environment and was not able to see the csv file.

Does anyone know if adding a csv file directly to a plugin introduce security risks?

Comment: it depends entirely on how you're reading the data and what you're doing with it - there are plenty of circumstances where you may wish to read from static files into php - could you please describe your scenario in a little more detail? feel free to include a bit of php that your plugin uses to locate the file and read the bytes

Comment: We have inventory pages where we need to change specific data in the frontend on a consistent basis based on specs we need to abide by for our clients. The code being used to read the data and place within an array is: (couldn't get it to format nicely)

Comment: $filePath = sprintf('%s/PATH-TO-DIR', WP_PLUGIN_DIR);
$fh = fopen($filePath, 'r+');
        while (($line = fgetcsv($fh)) !== false ) {
            $this->packageMatchingValues[] = [
                'key1' => $line[0],
                'key2' => $line[1],
                'key3' => $line[2],
                'key4' => explode('/', $line[3]),
                'key5' => $line[4],
                'key6' => $line[5],
                'key7' => $line[6],
            ];
        }
        fclose($fh);